# Create folder outline with CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to create a folder outline using CSS below you can see my code, but there are a few problems. It is the upper right corner that haunts me, it is quite light compared to the rest of the folder.

What is the best way to fix my code so that it does not have defects?

Or is it better to rewrite everything? I'm not very good at CSS.

```css
.wrapper_folder {
    @include folder;
}

@mixin folder {
    height: 348px;
    width: clamp(150px, 100%, 466px);
    &::after {
        bottom: 0;
        content: '';
        height: 306px;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 23px;
        background-color: white;
        width: clamp(150px, 100%, 466px);
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    &::before {
        top: 19px;
        z-index: 1;
        content: '';
        height: 22px;
        position: absolute;
        width: calc(50% + 20px);
        background-color: white;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border-bottom: 25px solid white;
        filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px black);
        background: radial-gradient(circle 23px at top right,#0000 95%,white ) top right;
    }
    
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 23px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;

    & > .folder_name {
        @include folderName;
    }
    & > .folder_box {
        @include folderBox;
    }
}

@mixin folderName {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 42px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 23px;
    width: calc(50% - 3px);
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    & > p{
        margin-top: 21px;
        margin-left: -19px;
    }
}

@mixin folderBox {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_folder three_folder">
    <div class="folder_name">
        <p class="folder_name_title">folder</p>
   </div>
    <div class="folder_box">
        <span class="folder_box_description"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your stack snippet just shows up as a plain link for me as text that says "folder". Is that what I'm supposed to see?

Comment: Please describe the desired behavior clearly.